Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1
I'm working with Flutter. When I run my app, everthing is ok, but for Firebase I nedd to add Certificate imprint. From myApp\android in a terminal I try ./gradlew.bat signingReport to get the imprint but I always get this error:
> Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1.
  Required by:
      unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.4.1
   > No matching variant of com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5' but:
       - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
           - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
           - Other compatible attribute:
               - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
       - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
               - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
       - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8      
           - Other compatible attribute:
               - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
       - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
               - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')


This is file settings.gradle:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.1" apply false
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.0" apply false
}

This is my gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

This is my Flutter version:

